# Linq EF Include() with Select() new type lost included

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```cs
context.Projects
.Include(x => x.Members) //List<Member> public class Member
.Include(x => x.Members.Select(z => z.City)) //public class City
.ToList();
```

Select from **Projects**

include list of **project.Members**

include each of **project.Members.City**

Need add some data to result

```cs
context.Projects
.Include(x => x.Members) 
.Include(x => x.Members.Select(z => z.City)) 
.Select(x => new {
    Project = x,
    Amount = 22
})
.ToList();
```

**Project** properties is filled but **Members** is null

Question 1 - how include **Project.Members** with **new { Project = x }**

I do next

```cs
context.Projects
.Include(x => x.Members) //List<Member>
.Include(x => x.Members.Select(z => z.City)) //City is navigation property
.Select(x => new {
    Project = x,
    Members = x.Members,
    Amount = 22
})
.ToList();
```

**Project** properties is filled and **Members** is filled but Members[0].City is null

Question 2 - how fill Members[0].City

P.S.

EntityFramework 6

```cs
public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectMember> Members { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectMember
{
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public Guid CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}
```

P.S.S

This work - but code overhead

```cs
context.Projects
.Include(x => x.Members) //List<Member>
.Include(x => x.Members.Select(z => z.City)) //City is navigation property
.Select(x => new {
    Project = x,
    Members = x.Members.Select(z => new {
        Item = z,
        City= z.City
    }).ToList(),
    Amount = 22
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Is this EF 6 or 7?

Comment: can you show your Projects class?

Comment: Add info: EntityFramework 6 and part of classes

Comment: You can try moving the `.Include()` to the end of the statement like `.Include(x => x.Project.Members).Include(x => x.Project.Members).Select(z => z.City)`

Comment: Move or add to end = "The result type of the query is neither an EntityType nor a CollectionType with an entity element type. An Include path can only be specified for a query with one of these result types."

Comment: This work - but code overhead Members = x.Members.Select(z => new {
        Item = z,
        City= z.City
    }).ToList(),

Comment: @Alexander Derck - Yes its - work. Please create comment as Answer

Comment: They recommend us on using this methods, yet all these ;down sides are not mentioned and not even a proper solution has been given to make this work as expected it would be.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any operations you do after the includes (except for filtering) will cause the includes to be discarded. By calling `AsEnumerable` after the includes, you will make sure the query gets executed then and the rest of the operations will be done in memory:

```
context.Projects 
       .Include(x => x.Members) 
       .Include(x => x.Members.Select(z => z.City))
       .AsEnumerable() 
       .Select(x => new { Project = x, Amount = 22 }) 
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Strangely enough, I am using EF 6.0 and my Include only accepts Include("Table") or nameof(Table)

Comment: Manually add a using for system.data.entity then the lambda is available as well

Comment: This is like looping the query thrice. so expensive

Answer (score 1):

Declare your  navigation properties as virtual,list as ICollection, and let EF replace with its concrete implementation when hydrating your entities:

```
public class Project
    {
        public Project { 
            Members = new HashSet<ProjectMember>(); 
        }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProjectMember> Members { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectMember
    {
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

        public Guid CityId { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Declaring as virtual - its many problem with serialization to json. I need manage which property when loaded (Include)

Comment: I know this is a late comment, but entities should almost never be serialized to JSON.  Map the properties you need into models prior to serialization to avoid the dreaded "Circular reference found on entity..." error.