# Linq - Order by in Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a situation where OrderBy need to be done for Include object. This is how I have tried so far

```
Customers query = null;

try
{
    query = _context.Customers
        .Include(x => x.CustomerStatus)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.StatusNavigation)
        .Select(x => new Customers()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Address = x.Address,
            Contact = x.Contact,
            Name = x.Name,
            CustomerStatus = new List<CustomerStatus>
            {
                x.CustomerStatus.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault()
            }
        })
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

The above code successfully ordering the include element but it is not including it's child table.
Eg: Customer include CustomerStatus but CustomerStatus not including StatusNavigation tables.

I even tried with this but neither it can help me

```
_context.Customers
    .Include(x => x.CustomerStatus.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault())
    .ThenInclude(x => x.StatusNavigation).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3);
```

What am I doing wrong please guide me someone

Even I tried this way

```
var query = _context.CustomerStatus
    .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault())
    .Include(x => x.StatusNavigation)
    .Join(_context.Customers, first => first.CustomerId, second => second.Id, (first, second) => new Customers
    {
        Id = second.Id,
        Name = second.Name,
        Address = second.Address,
        Contact = second.Contact,
        CustomerStatus = new List<CustomerStatus> {
            new CustomerStatus
            {
                Id = first.Id,
                CustomerId = first.CustomerId,
                Date = first.Date,
                StatusNavigation = first.StatusNavigation
            }
        },
    }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3);
```

but this is hitting a databases a 3 times and filtering the result in memory.
First select all data from customer status and then from status and then from customer then it filter all the data in memory. Is there any other efficient way to do this??

This is how I have prepared by entity class
[image]

Comment: Take a look onto it: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833

Comment: We need to see your entity classes.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - I have updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Chris Pratt mentioned once you are doing **new Customer** inside the select you are creating a new model. You are discarding the models build by the EntityFramework. My suggestion would be have the query just:

```
query = _context.Customers
    .Include(x => x.CustomerStatus)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.StatusNavigation);
```

Like this you would have an IQueryable object which it would not be executed unless you do a select from it:

```
var customer3 = query.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==3)
```

Which returns the customer and the interlinked tables (CustomerStatus and StatusNavigation). Then you can create the object that you want:

```
var customer = new Customers()
    {
        Id = customer3.Id,
        Address = customer3.Address,
        Contact = customer3.Contact,
        Name = x.Name,
        CustomerStatus = new List<CustomerStatus>
        {
            customer3.CustomerStatus.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault()
        }
    })
```

In this way you can reuse the query for creating different response objects and have a single querying to database, but downside is that more memory is used then the original query (even though it shouldn't be too much of an issue).

If the model that is originally return from database doesn't meet the requirements (i.e. you always need to do: **CustomerStatus = new List {...}** ) it might indicate that the database schema is not well defined to the needs of the application, so a refactoring might be needed.

Answer (score 5):

What I think is happening is that you are actually overriding the `Include` and `ThenInclude`. `Include` is explicitly to eager-load a navigation property. However, you're doing a couple of things that are likely hindering this.

First, you're selecting into a new `Customer`. That alone may be enough to break the logic of `Include`. Second, you're overriding what gets put in the `CustomerStatus` collection. That should ideally be just loaded in automatically via `Include`, but by altering it to just have the first entity, you're essentially throwing away the effect of `Include`. (Selecting a relationship is enough to cause a join to be issued, without explicitly calling `Include`). Third, the `ThenInclude` is predicated on the `Include`, so overriding that is probably throwing out the `ThenIncude` as well.

All this is conjecture. I haven't done anything exactly like what you're doing here before, but nothing else makes sense.

Try selecting into a new `CustomerStatus` as well:

```
CustomerStatus = x.CustomerStatus.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).Select(s => new CustomerStatus
{
    x.Id,
    x.Status,
    x.Date,
    x.CustomerId,
    x.Customer,
    x.StatusNavigation
 })
```

You can remove the `Include`/`ThenInclude` at that point, because the act of selecting these relationships will cause the join.

Comment: I need only one Column from that query. I only want to know whether the customer is active or not. I don't need a whole history of that custoemr

Comment: @ChrisHadfield I think this answer is correct. He just didn't add first or default at the end. But I think that in this case you should not use the object for pulling the data and make a view poco or an anonymous object since they EF object will not actually be the same when you pull them directly.

Answer (score 0):

After Reading from Couple of sources [(Source 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36078646/7482427) and [(Source 2)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6177#issuecomment-236229259). I think what is happening is that If you use `select` after `Include`. It disregards `Include` even if you are using `Include` query data in `select`. So to solve this use `.AsEnumerable()` before calling `select`.

```
query = _context.Customers
    .Include(x => x.CustomerStatus)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.StatusNavigation)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new Customers()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Address = x.Address,
        Contact = x.Contact,
        Name = x.Name,
        CustomerStatus = new List<CustomerStatus>
        {
            x.CustomerStatus.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault()
        }
    })
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3);
```

Comment: AsEnumerable will just pull everything into memory.

Comment: @FilipCordas Yes u are Correct!